# Symfony4 extending entity does not add Entity column to database schema

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am developing symfony 4.2 application. I have entity Meal and OrderItem. OrderItem should have all Meal entity properties + few of it's own. The problem is with ManyToOne relationship column. It is not added to order_item table.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html 
I tried following "Class Table Inheritance" and "Mapped Superclasses". Example from "Mapped Superclasses" does not add  $mappedRelated1 to EntitySubClass . And example from "Class Table Inheritance" removes every other extended field from Meal class and adds some kind of "dtype" column to Meal table.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OrderItemRepository")
 */
class OrderItem extends Meal
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Order", inversedBy="orderItems")
     */
    private $order;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     */
    private $amount;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MealRepository")
 */
class Meal
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type("float")
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     mimeTypes={"image/jpeg", "image/png"}
     * )
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Menu", inversedBy="meals")
     */
    protected $menu;
}
```

I expect to have "menu_id" column in "order_item" table, which would have relation to Menu entity.

I know that I could copy all the properties from Meal to OrderItem, but that does not sound right.

EDIT:

Both Meal and OrderItem should be able to have it's instance.

Answer (score 0):

menu_id column is already exists in meal

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Menu", inversedBy="meals")
     */
    protected $menu;
```

OrderItem class doesnt need to have just because it is already subclass of meal.
Also you dont need to copy all propertites from Meal to OrderItem.
u can check [php extends](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) here

Comment: I need to have that field in my database table

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I used Trait instead of inheritance and the problem was solved.

Your class will be like this

```
trait MealInfoTrait
{   
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type("float")
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     mimeTypes={"image/jpeg", "image/png"}
     * )
     */
    protected $image;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Menu", inversedBy="meals")
     */
    protected $menu;
}
```

Then, change you Meal class

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MealRepository")
 */
class Meal
{
    use MealInfoTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

And do the same with your OrderItem class. Don't forget to add the id for the database.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OrderItemRepository")
 */
class OrderItem
{
    use MealInfoTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Order", inversedBy="orderItems")
     */
    private $order;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type("string")
     */
    private $amount;
}
```